# Yaml with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a python3.6 virtual environment. I an trying to run some keras code and came across this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K
  File "Keras-2.0.8/keras/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "Keras-2.0.8/keras/activations.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .engine import Layer
  File "Keras-2.0.8/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .topology import InputSpec
  File "Keras-2.0.8/keras/engine/topology.py", line 8, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "Keras-2.0.8/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'error'
```

I saw a few other posts regarding this but those all suggest that the problems may be that I am using the python 2.7 version for python3. However, I don not think this is the case since I am in a python 3.6 virtual environment.

I also saw some comments about re-installing/upgrading yaml with python3.6 specifically. I thought doing a pip install in the virtual environment would fix this but it did not seem to help. Any suggestions regarding how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

Side Note: the code I am trying to run is test.py from [this](https://github.com/jackyko1991/vnet-tensorflow) repo when I come across the error.